# Random executable output with CMake

Tags: cmake, clion

Can I have a random name for the executable file of each build?
Or, in another words, a different name for the executable of each build action?

I wonder if a random-variable could be inserted into the build-tool-chain.

The reason of such a name is that my company's virus-checking is quite slow -- it took a long long time checking each executable, even longer then the build.

I'm using CLion 2016.2 on Win7, tool-chain is MinGW_w64_5.0, bundled CMake 3.5.2

Comment: It turned out that the cause of the slow-deleting-exe-file  is --- the "Application Experience" service. http://superuser.com/a/239164/446855

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always define `POST_BUILD` steps that call another CMake script. The only downside in the following approach would be that you can't - since it's random - reuse the executable's output name in CMake itself:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(RandomExeName)

file(WRITE main.cpp "int main() { return 0; }")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} 
    POST_BUILD 
       COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -D _file:PATH="$<TARGET_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}>"
                                -P ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CopyToRandom.cmake
)
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY SUFFIX ".temp")
```

**CopyToRandom.cmake**

```
string(RANDOM _random)
file(GLOB _old_files RELATIVE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}" "*.exe")
execute_process(
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E remove ${_old_files}
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E copy "${_file}" "${_random}.exe"
)

# generate shortcut
get_filename_component(_name "${_file}" NAME_WE)
file(
   WRITE "${_name}.sh"
       "#!/bin/bash\n"
       "${_random}.exe"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. Or you have to reconfigure for every build.

Regarding your actual problem: Advice the virus checker to exclude your build directories.

Comment: I'm trying with CMake string(TIMESTAMP ...) or string(RANDOM  ... )

Comment: They will be evaluated during configure time and stay until you rerun CMake.